# Error en trigger laravel

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, estoy haciendo un trigger que se ejecute cada que realice una venta y me descuente de mi stock pero marca un error en la linea 4. Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy utilizando HeidiSQl
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

me parece que la forma correcta seria:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGG` AFTER INSERT ON `venta`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

UPDATE material 
SET Cantidad = Cantidad - NEW.Cantidad
WHERE idMaterial = NEW.idMaterial;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Dependiendo de la versión de mysql o mariadb podría cambiar el uso del delimiter, podrias probarlo de esta manera tambien:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGG` AFTER INSERT ON `venta`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

UPDATE material 
SET Cantidad = Cantidad - NEW.Cantidad
WHERE idMaterial = NEW.idMaterial;

END;
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: El DELIMITER hasta las versiones recientes sigue siendo necesario